# Wordpress wp_mail function crashing website

Tags: wp-mail, phpmailer

So i've been trying to send email from my functions.php script.

When wp_mail function is fired, my entire website crashes.

I have enabled all the error display settings in wp-config.

I literally copied and pasted the function directly from wordpress.org website, but still my email function causes crash.

```
 function send_email(){
        $from = "Admin <no-reply@lamza.co.za>";
        $to = "testing@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Lamza Activation";
        $message = 'Testing 1 2 3';
        $headers[] = "From:" . $from . PHP_EOL;
        $headers[] = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

When i comment wp_mail, my website does not crash, if i uncomment wp_mail, my website crashes.

I do not know whats wrong. I can send test emails using Easy WP SMTP, so i know emails can be sent from my side.

Comment: If it's crashing then you should be getting an error in your server or PHP error logs. Can you find that? (And nowadays WordPress should email the error to you the first time too.)

Comment: If that doesn't help, try adding trace to wp_mail, e.g. error_log lines before each major part of it, so you can see how far its getting before it crashes and what the state is

Comment: Hi Rup, Thank you very much, I found the error_log file in wp-content folder, the issue was that PHPMAILER was in the src document and i had to change the directory in the pluggable.php